# jquery удалить обработчик события

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

Решил недавно заюзать для сайта **`pjax`**.

Есть следующий код

```js
function resetEvents() {
    $(document).off('click', '[data-type="get_form"]')
}
....
$(document).on('click', '[data-type="get_form"]', handler)
$(document).on('click', '[data-type="ajax"]', handler)
$(document).on('click', '[data-type="delete"]', handler)
.....
```

Код рабочий но для каждого `on` надо писать свой `off`. Но так как скрипты уже прописаны давно и их сотни полностью переделывать не хочется.

Я пробовал делать так

```js
$(document).off('click', '#container *')
```

Но результата никакого, суть такова что надо для всех элементов в контейнере прибить обработчики событий, потому что после перехода на другую страницу и обратно кнопки начинаю срабатывать по несколько раз.

Какой вариант может быть для решения такой задачи? Или придется переписывать все?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function handler() {
  console.log("click");
}

function clickOn() {
  $(document).on('click', '[data-type="get_form"]', handler);
}

function clickOff() {
  $(document).off('click', handler);
}
```

```css
[data-type="get_form"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-type="get_form"></div>
<br/>
<button onclick="clickOn()">ON</button>
<button onclick="clickOff()">OFF</button>
```

---

> после перехода на другую страницу и обратно кнопки начинают срабатывать
>   по несколько раз

Вот с этим и надо разбираться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но это немного не то. Дело в том что пример утрированный и вместо handler на самом деле анонимная функция. И таких от обработчиков очень много и они все разные само собой. Появилась мысль написать функцию которая будет регистрировать обработчики и записывать в массив и когда надо вызывать другую функцию которая перед отправкой запроса будет удалять все обработчики которые в массиве.

Answer (score 2):

Я понимаю, что уже наверно не актуально, но может поможет другим.

Для меня работает подобная схема:

```js
$('a[href], button').off("click.unique_namespace").on({
  'click.unique_namespace': event => { /* ваша анонимная функция */ }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Тут unique_namespace - пространство имен, уникальное для каждой вашей анонимной функции.
Если лямбд действительно очень много, то можно генерировать это пространство имен как довольно большую случайную последовательность

```js
const current_namespace = Math.random() * Math.random();
$('a[href], button').off(`click.${current_namespace}`).on({
  `click.${current_namespace}`: event => { /* ваша анонимная функция */ }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Или любым другим образом.

Можно также завести счетчик и тем самым обеспечить уникальность пространства имен.